# Limiting file types/extensions when uploading files in an HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

Is there any way to limit the type of file that can be uploaded using an HTML form via PHP? For example, I want to limit uploads to only `.pdf` files.

Comment: server-side limit or client-side limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Server side**

Yes use superglobal `$_FILES`. look at this documentation page : [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

It will get through basics, and then just look for file type, which is what you need to check with.

**Client side**

There are many ways to do this, but you can achieve this simply :

```
if((document.form1.upload.value.lastIndexOf(".jpg")==-1) {
   alert("Please upload only .jpg extention file");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: there is also a `type` part to the `$_FILES` array which makes things much muuuuch easier ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Yes. just look in the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array and read the file type.